# Java Stream: How to find id from json?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a json as below and a similar classes respect to it `MyClient`:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "partners": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4857"
            },
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4967"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "partners": [
            {
                "configuration": {
                    "connect-fleet-sync": false
                },
                "id": "c3354af5-16e3-4713-b1f5-a5369c0b13d6"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need a method which receives the uuid and it returns **id**.

Fr example `findClientId("cf89cbc5-0886-48cc-81e7-ca6123bc4967")` and then it returns `2`:

Here is what i have tried:

```
  public static void findClientId(String partnerId, MyClient[] allMyClients) {
    Stream.of(allMyClients)
        .map(MyClient::getPartners)
        .forEach(Partner::getPartnerId)
        .filter(
            partner ->partner.id.equals(partnerId)))
    .map(MyClient::getId);
  }
```

But it complains `Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context`
in the line `.forEach(Partner::getPartnerId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Stream.forEach` is void. You can't invoke `.filter` or any other method after it. Beside that, `.map(MyClient::getPartners)` would make you lose `MyClient` information in the pipeline while it's `MyClient.getId` that you want. You'd have to use a nested stream to for filtering on partner list in each client.

Your code should be:

```
public static String findClientId(String partnerId, MyClient[] allMyClients) {
    return Stream.of(allMyClients)
            .filter(client -> client.getPartners()
                    .stream()
                    .anyMatch(partner -> partner.getPartnerId().equals(partnerId)))
            .map(MyClient::getId)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null); // change to whatever is desired
}
```